# SAT Probability and Counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given the letters A, A, B, B, C, D, E

How many different arrangements are possible that begins and ends with the letter "A"?

1. B,B,B,G,G 
   Three boys and two girls shown above are lined up side by side in a single row so that boys and girls are lined up in groups respectively. How many different arrangements of the childern are possible?
2. There are 3 Republicans and 2 Democrats on a Senate committee. if a 3-person subcommittee is to be formed from this committee, what is the probability of selecting 2 Republicans and 1 democrat?
3. An urn contains 4 white marbles and 5 black marbles, all of equal size. If two marbles are drawn at random with no replacement, what is the probability that 2 marbles are different colors?
4. If the 5 cards A, B, C, D, E are placed in a row so that cards B and C must be next to each other, how many different arrangements are possible?

Comment: The leftmost of B and C can be placed in $4$ ways. For each of these ways, there are $2$ ways to decide which of B or C will occupy that position. Then the position of the other is determined, and the $3$ remaining slots can be filled in $3!$ ways, for a total of $(4)(2)(3!)$.

Comment: I've tried 5! for the first question and I've got 120 as the answer. I don't understand why one would divide 5! by 2 to arrive at the final answer of 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the $A's$ in the corner, so you're left with $B,B, C,D,E$. Then you can select 2 places for the $B's$ in $5C2$ ways (with $5C2=5!/2!3!=10$). Then each of these $5C2$ choices can be combined with any of the $3!$ arrangements for $C,D,E$, for a total of  $$5C2 \times 3!=10\times 6=60 $$ ways of arranging the letters. For a more forceful answer, the number of ways of arranging the letters is a multinomial coefficient $\frac {5!}{2!1!1!1!}=60$; in general, if you have a total of $n$ letters, where some are repeated $n_1,..,n_k$ times respectively, with  $n=n_1+n_2+...+n_k$  then the total number of arrangements is $$\frac {n!}{n_!!n_2!..n_k!} $$. Here you have (after you fix the letters at the two ends), $n=5; n_1=2, n_3=1=n_4$.

For the other questions, consider the sample space in each. I assume the events are independent, so that you multiply the respective probabilities. For example, for 2, first count the number of ways of selecting 2 republicans and 1 democrat from 3,2 congresspersons respectively. Then (assuming independence) consider the number of ways of forming a subcommittee with any three congresspersons. For 3, do a similar thing: consider the number of ways of getting two marbles of different colors. How many pairs $(w,B)$ can you have, out of the total number of pairs.

Hope that puts you on the right track.

Comment: why don't you consider the As at both ends? Wouldn't they make repeats?

Comment: Ben, if you consider the arrangements without the $A's$ at the ends, then there are just two spaces to put the two $A's$ at the ends, and there is just one way of doing this. Is this what you meant? I am fixing the two A's at the end, since this is the condition you give at the beginning of the problem, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Ben: would you like some help with the other questions 2,3,4?

Comment: yes and thank you

Comment: @Ben: I edited to give more hints for the other questions; let me know if you have followups.

Comment: Can you explain your method for the first question: " Then you can select 2 places for the B′s in 5C2 ways (with 5C2=5!/2!3!=10)". I don't understand the method.

Comment: The arrangement has the form $AXXXXXA$ with the $X$ entries replaced by $BBCDE$ in some order. Two of the $X$ entries will be replaced by $B$. So to place the $B$s you need to choose two places out of the available $5$.

Comment: @Ben: If you already selected a place for the A's and the B's, then there are only 3 places left for the C,D,E, so the 3 can be arranged in 3! ways.

Comment: @user99680 If you solve for C,D, E before solving for the two Bs, can you use 5C3 with C, D, and E? ? Why can't C,D, and E be solved with 5C3?

Comment: @Ben: It is a nice exercise to show that the result does not depend on the order in which you put the letters in: Say you fix your A's at the ends. Now you want to put C,D,E in, in 5C3 ways (because different orderings give you different arrangements). But then you can rearrange C,D,E in 3! ways, so you multiply 5C3 by 3! . And then the remaining 2 A's must choose two spots, which can only be done in one way, as 2C2, for a total of 5C3(3!)=60, the same as before. It is a nice exercise to show that for a general setup, the total does not depend on the order in which you make the choices.